# Unexpected non-void return value in void function when returns an array

Tags: swift, function

I would like to get help cuz I'm really confused. It says "Unexpected non-void return value in void function" when it returns an array. I think that my problem is brackets, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
func getWords() -> Array<Any>{

           ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("addedWords").observe(.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
                var tempWords = DataSnapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
                var words = Array(tempWords.keys)
                print(words)

                return words
                })}
```

Comment: Your problem is trying to return from an async block.

Comment: Could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t just return `words` in your `closure`. First of all it´s an async method second you need to return a value outside of the closure which will be called before the closure. You need to have a `completionHandler` instead of returning `Array<Any>`. In that case you can pass the value if and when it succeeds. Something like this:

```
func getWords(onCompletion: @escaping (Array<Any>) -> Void) {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("addedWords").observe(.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in
        var tempWords = DataSnapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        var words = Array(tempWords.keys)
        print(words)
        onCompletion(words)
    })
}
```

To call it:

```
getWords(onCompletion: { (words) in
    print(words)
})
```